# How to get multiple streams from WebRTC PeerConnection

Tags: webrtc

According to [RTCPeerConnection.ontrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/ontrack) documentation, "ontrack" event suppose to fire for each incoming streams. I have a PeerConnection with two video streams, after connection, "ontrack" fires two times (up to here everything is OK). But both times it sends same stream out, so I end up with two identical video, I am sure sender is sending two different streams, dimension and frame rate of them are different and I can clearly see in chrome://webrtc-internals/ that 2 video streams have different frame size/rate.

Here is PeerConnection ontrack code:

```
        this.peerConnection.ontrack = function(evt) {
            console.log("PeerConnection OnTrack event: ", evt.streams);
            that.emit('onRemoteStreamAdded', evt.streams);
        };
```

I don't assume `evt.streams` has 1 object, so I did not write `evt.streams[0]`.

Here is Chrome console log:
[image: Chrome console log]

As it is obvious from log `getRemoteStreams()` returns only one object. How is it possible `ontrack` fires two time when it has only one stream, and why second RTCRtpTransceiver does not make a new stream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it after few hours of struggling with different browsers and reading documentations several times!

Problem starts at [MediaStream.id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/id), it suppose to be unique but `<video>` element in HTML5 only listens to first track inside each stream. PeerConnection adds new transceivers (as MediaStreamTrack) to same MediaStream, so no matter how many times `ontrack` handler fires, you get exact same `MediaStream` objects, but each time you have new unique `MediaStreamTrack` inside the `RTCTrackEvent`.

Solution is to create new `MediaStream` object for each new `MediaStreamTrack` inside `ontrack` handler.

```
this.peerConnection.ontrack = function(event) {
    that.emit('onRemoteStreamAdded', new MediaStream([event.track]));
};
```

Or, more like standard examples:

```
pc.ontrack = function(event) {
  document.getElementById("received_video").srcObject = new MediaStream([event.track]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You get two *tracks* which are part of a single stream. You can see that in the event.track property, one of them should be audio, the other video.

See https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/the-evolution-of-webrtc/ for background information on how streams and tracks work.

Comment: Thank you for not reading my question!
First, I don't have two streams, I have more than 5. Second, all of them are videos without audio track, see my question. Third, this was not WebRTC fault, it is partially HTML <video> element implementation and also MediaStream implementation fault in browser.
Check my answer for correct solution.

Comment: are you calling `addTrack(track)` on the other end of the connection instead of `addTrack(track, stream)`? That would explain the behaviour as in that case everything will go into a catchall MediaStream on the receiver. That is generally considered to be a not so good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is too old but I will add this answer for the future visitors. In WebRTC application, on both the ends changes has to be made. On the sender side multiple videos has to be added to the track separately(not with the usual procedure). With normal procedure both the streams will be combined on the receiver end. On the receiver end, you need to check the event.stream and even.track and add them separately to the appropriate  tags.